# Shifting the mean of a composite function of deterministic and random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

For a project I am involved in relating to communication, I have the following model:

$L = f(r).X$

where
$X$ is a lognormal random variable with *zero mean* in the logarithmic scale and standard deviation of $\sigma$
$f(r)$ is a deterministic function of independent variable $r$

I already have numerous outcomes (realizations) of the above function using random number generators. I now need to transform the above so that the mean of the lognormal distribution is changed to some deterministic function of $r$, say $m(r)$, in the **logarithmic scale**.

---

I have taken the following approach to transform the outcomes:

Take log on both sides,

$log(L) = log(f(r)) + log(X)$

since the $log$ of a lognormal random variable is a normal random variable, the mean is simply changed by adding a function $m$ (with deterministic values in the log scale) which depends on $r$,

$log(L) = log(f(r)) + log(X) + m(r)$

The new mean of the stochastic term $log(X) + m(r)$ is now $m(r)$, and by taking antilog on both sides, I can get back my function $L$ in the linear scale with a shifted mean in the $log$ scale.

---

**Hence**, given a value $l$ as an outcome of $L$ for some value $r$, I can transform as follows:

$l_m = antilog(log(l) + m(r))$

where $l_m$ refers to the transformed value with log mean $m$. Is the above approach correct? If not, can you tell me where I'm going wrong?